# How to get code to continue prompting user for next number?

Tags: java

The question I'm working on is,

> "Write is a Multiple that determines, for a pair of integers, whether
>   the second integer is a multiple of the first. The method will take 2
>   integer arguments and return true if the second is a multiple of the
>   first and false otherwise. [Hint: Use the remainder operator].
>   Incorporate this method into an application that inputs a series of
>   pairs of integers (1 pair at a time) and determines whether the second
>   value in each pair is a multiple of the first."

Now, I have a program written that somewhat works, but I just cant seem to get it to keep going. It should stop when 0 is pressed but it doesn't get past the first integer.

I did get it to run for one cycle when I change while (first != 0); to while (first == 0);.

Did I just leave something out or have something completely wrong? Any info would help.

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multiples 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Len Rogers - Programming Assignment 4\n");

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        int first; // first number
        int second; // second number

        System.out.print( "Enter first number (0 to exit): " );
        first = input.nextInt();

        // set 0 as the sentinel value, since we cannot divide by 0
        while (first != 0);
        {

            System.out.print("Enter second number: " );
            second = input.nextInt();

            if ( ismultiple(first,  second ) )
                System.out.printf( "true\n\n", second, first );
            else
                System.out.printf( "false\n\n" , second, first );

            System.out.print( "Enter first number (0 to exit): " );
            first = input.nextInt();
         } // end while loop
    } // end main

    // determin if the firest integer is a multiple of the second
    public static boolean ismultiple( int firstNumber, int secondNumber )
    {
        return secondNumber % firstNumber == 0;
    } // end method multiple
} // end class Multiples
```

Comment: What specifically does this have to do with NetBeans 8?

Comment: Hint: You should always have a following call  `input.nextLine()` after some `input.nextInt()` or `input.next()` (or similar) as the latter do not consume the pending newline character that was entered in the console.

Comment: Problem is  semicolon(terminator) just after while.Remove it and it will work

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose..Its not correct.

Comment: NetBeans 8 is what I am using to build the code. I didn't know if that made a difference as apposed to the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you Ankit Tripathi !!   I just tried it and now it is just fine. I feel like such a dork for overlooking that.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
do {

} while( first != 0 )
```

is the loop you are looking for as it prevents you needing to have separate code to read the first input

If you use readline then check that what your reading can be cast to an int otherwise quit you should be able to get what you want.